# ¿Por que hay preguntas que las marca como activas sin que haya habido ninguna modificación?

Tags: soporte, preguntas, preguntas-activas

Aquí un ejemplo: [¿Cómo conectar mi aplicación en Android a un servidor de base de datos?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/11606/c%C3%B3mo-conectar-mi-aplicaci%C3%B3n-en-android-a-un-servidor-de-base-de-datos)

En esta pregunta marca que la última fecha en la que ha estado activa la pregunta es hoy. Entiendo que esa fecha se indica cuando hay una modificación (tanto de pregunta como de respuestas) o ha sido relanzada por el usuario Comunidad.

Sin embargo, en este caso, ninguno de los tres casos anteriores se dan.

Por lo tanto, ¿por qué marca como que la pregunta está activa hoy si no se ha producido ningún cambio ni evento sobre ella? ¿Es algún tipo de evento especial que realiza Stackoverflow para activar de nuevo preguntas antiguas?

Comment: Por lo que veo, tiene una respuesta nueva que luego fue eliminada. Necesitas los privilegios de 10k para ver la respuesta eliminada, al parecer incluso en la timeline: https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/11606/timeline :(

Comment: @EmanuelVe Acostumbrado a la beta, contaba con que podía ver las respuestas eliminadas aunque intuía que algo raro pasaba. Gracias por el aporte :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para ver algunos eventos, o sucesión de estos, se requieren de ciertos privilegios. Tal es el caso de las respuestas eliminadas las cuales modifican el estado de las preguntas al ser publicadas, pero al ser eliminadas no deshacen ese cambio de estado.

Referencias

- [Acceso a herramientas de moderación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)
- [What is the difference between "hot" and "active" questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2040/289691)

Comment: Muchas gracias @Rubén, acostumbrado a la beta contaba con que podía ver las respuestas eliminadas aunque intuía que algo raro pasaba. Muchas gracias por el aporte :)