# ¿Por qué algunos usuarios pueden realizar comentarios con 1 de reputación?

Tags: soporte, comentarios, privilegios

Acabo de ver algo que me ha llamado la atención.

En esta pregunta: [Cambiar un texto utilizando CSS](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/95510/cambiar-un-texto-utilizando-css) el usuario que ha comentado tiene 1 de reputación, por lo que en teoría no tendría que poder comentar hasta ganar el privilegio.

Os dejo una captura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Es algún tipo de bug? Lo que también se me ha ocurrido es que pueda ser que un moderador haya podido mover el comentario (lo cual desconozco si lo pueden hacer).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Otra vez :)](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2671/por-que-hay-preguntas-que-las-marca-como-activas-sin-que-haya-habido-ninguna-mo#comment9286_2671) se trata de una publicacion eliminada, pero como ya lo has adivinado,  en este caso el post fue convertido a comentario por un moderador.

No se trata de un bug, sino de una funcionalidad.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Me queda la duda si el comentario de Jorgesys es automatico, puesto que no es el correcto.

Comment: No, tiene toda la pinta de ser manual. Si usara el automático de la cola de "publicaciones de baja calidad" al mismo tiempo eliminaría la publicación.

Comment: ¡¡Muchas gracias de nuevo!! Me imaginaba que sería cosa de algún moderador, pero no estaba del todo seguro :)

Comment: Siempre me ha sorprendido que se convierta en comentario una no respuesta de un usuario sin reputación para comentar. Se está ayudando a saltarse el sistema de privilegios de SO.

Answer (score 0):

Francisco, no es un bug, como bien comenta Emanuel, es una funcionalidad de moderación, ya que para que un usuario tenga el [privilegio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) de [realizar comentarios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), se requieren como mínimo [50 puntos de reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

El comentario que señalas en realidad no fue del usuario, un moderador tiene la opción de poder convertir una "respuesta" en comentario, incluso optar por también agregar los comentarios de esta "respuesta" como comentarios.